# Is there any efficient way to evaluate the following summation?

Tags: summation

Given $r_1,\ldots,r_n\in\mathbb{R}$, the objective is to compute the following summation:
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{x_1,\ldots,x_n\in \{0,1\}\\x_1+\ldots+x_n<n/2}} {r_1}^{x_1}\cdots{r_n}^{x_n},
\end{align}
i.e., low order terms of $(r_1+1)\ldots(r_n+1)$. Summation in exhaustive manner requires exponential complexity in $n$. I guess that the summation can be simplified if indices have a particular structure. For instance, say $x_1+\ldots+x_n=0 \ (\text{mod } 2)$, then the summation boils down to
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\left((r_1+1)\ldots(r_n+1)-(r_1-1)\ldots(r_n-1)\right).
\end{align}
Is there any efficient summation method for my problem?

Comment: When you say efficient, do you mean you want something that fits in at most a few pages of handwritten work, or do you mean a good way for a computer to do it with some tolerance?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I mean the latter one.